# Trying to create file in datalake from webapp using java

Tags: java, web-applications, azure-active-directory, azure-data-lake

Below is the piece of code to create file in datalake. ADLException is thrown at client.createfile line.Checked with permission user has read,write and execute. Can some one help how to handle this.

try {

```
                     OutputStream stream = client.createFile("/Raw/TEST/"+FuFileName, IfExists.OVERWRITE);

                    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(stream);
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                        out.println("This is line #" + i);
                        out.format("This is the same line (%d), but using formatted output. %n", i);
                    }
                    out.close();
                } catch (ADLException ex) {
                    printExceptionDetails(ex);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.format(" Exception: %s%n Message: %s%n", ex.getClass().getName(), ex.getMessage());
                }
```

Comment: Please don't provide images of code. Please take a look at [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to give you a better idea of how to structure a question in a way that is more likely to get an answer.

Comment: @sql Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a file in Azure Data Lake Gen1 with Java, we can use the [service-to-service authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-service-to-service-authenticate-using-active-directory). The detailed steps are as below.

1. [Create an Active Directory web application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis)
   [image]
2. [Assign the Azure AD application to the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 account file or folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-service-to-service-authenticate-using-active-directory#step-3-assign-the-azure-ad-application-to-the-azure-data-lake-storage-gen1-account-file-or-folder)
   [image]
3. Code

```
 private static String clientId = "FILL-IN-HERE";
 private static String authTokenEndpoint = "FILL-IN-HERE";
 private static String clientKey = "FILL-IN-HERE";

 AccessTokenProvider provider = new ClientCredsTokenProvider(authTokenEndpoint, clientId, clientKey); 
private static String accountFQDN = "FILL-IN-HERE";  // full account FQDN, not just the account name
ADLStoreClient client = ADLStoreClient.createClient(accountFQDN, provider);

try {
String filename = "/a/b/c.txt";
OutputStream stream = client.createFile(filename, IfExists.OVERWRITE  );
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(stream);
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    out.println("This is line #" + i);
    out.format("This is the same line (%d), but using formatted output. %n", i);
}
out.close();
System.out.println("File created.");

}catch(Exception ex){
 System.out.format(" Exception: %s%n Message: %s%n", ex.getClass().getName(), ex.getMessage());
}
```

For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-java-sdk.

Comment: @sql Do you have any other concerns?